# Possible to view Spark History Server Logs in JSON?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to view the Spark History Server Logs in JSON? I am using the command from the REST API `curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/applications` but it keeps returning the data in HTML. This is very hard to parse since I'll need exact metrics from the logs. In particular, I am looking for the list of jobs running and current executors being used.